# jtl report which has xml data not able to create html in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to create report from jtl report to html report to in jmeter but the I am guessing the problem is, I am storing the response data in as xml in jtl with the below command due to which it shows error as below-

```
File 'C:\Users\sobhit.sharma\Documents\ig-load-test\report.jtl' does not contain the field names header, ensure the jmeter.save.saveservice.* properties are the same as when the CSV file was created or the file may be read incorrectly when generating report
```

An error occurred: Could not read sample <0>

```
C:\Users\sobhit.sharma\Documents\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin\jmeter -n -t test.jmx -Jthreads=20 -Jrampup=20 -Jiteration=1 -l testresult.jtl -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true -JconstantThrougput=20
```

other wise I am able to create my report in html.

and this is how my jtml file loos like-
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per [Generating Report Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) chapter of JMeter documentation:

> The dashboard generator is a modular extension of JMeter. Its default behavior is to read and process samples from **CSV files** to generate HTML files containing graph views.

It means that you cannot generate HTML reporting dashboard out of XML format of the .JTL results file.

Consider switching to the CSV format, to wit change this line:

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
```

to this one:

```
-Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
```

If you need to save response data when the error occurs - you can store it into a separate file using i.e. [Flexible File Writer listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/)

Comment: Flexible file writer listener is a good idea but dont you think it will be too much for jmeter to be writing into the file. And also I just want to write it only when its failure.